# Downloading a file generated through a python script which was called using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, angular

I have an app in angular and using that I'm running a python script to generate an excel sheet according to the data I'm sending as arguments. The script is being called as follows:

```
let python;
python = spawn('python', ['script1.py', JSON.stringify(eval(loguser))]);
```

Here `loguser` is a variable which has the data that I plan on sending to the script.

Now I want to download the file that is being created in the python script. In the end of the script I did `wb.save(excel_path)` where `excel_path` has the name of the file and the path where it is being saved. But this just saves the file at that location, I want to return that file to my JavaScript code and download it for the user. How should I do that?

If something is not clear or some more information is required, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: pass the filename to the pythonscript from node... then do whatever you want with it in node after ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Sure, but I don't really know what to do there..

Comment: you can use fs to open it and send the bytes wherever or to copy it to another place or you can email it somewhere... no one knows what you mean by "return to my javascript code and download it for the user" ... afaik spawn doesnt work except on server side so this isnt running in a webpage